# Group not inheriting access privileges for all tables

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I can't figure out why tables created by one user can be accessed by a read-only user, but not tables created by another user.

I have a `viewers` read-only group with this access:

```
-- Grant access to existing tables
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO viewers;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO viewers;

-- Grant access to future tables
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO viewers;
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO viewers;
```

I have two superusers in my database and one read-only user, all members of the group:

```
 Role name | Attributes | Member of 
-----------+------------+-----------
 a         | Superuser  | {viewers}
 b         | Superuser  | {viewers}
 readonly  |            | {viewers}
```

When I create a table as user `a`, the `readonly` user can access it. 
But when I create the table as user `b`, the `readonly` user gets  `permission denied for relation`.

When I check the grants, when the table is created by user `a`, the `viewers` group gets granted select automatically:

```
SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='testa'
;

 grantee | privilege_type 
---------+----------------
 viewers | SELECT
 a       | INSERT
 a       | SELECT
 a       | UPDATE
 a       | ...
```

But if the table is created by `b`, the the `viewers` group does not have that select privilege.

I'm sure it's simple, but I am not sure what commands will help me troubleshoot the permissions error. Where can I check to see the existing privileges and get the root of this?

Answer (score 2):

The group to which the users `a` or `b` belong does not affect the permissions on the tables created by these users.

There must be default privileges defined for `a`, but not for `b`.

Check with `\ddp` in `psql`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I thought that `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO viewers;` would have covered that. Do I need to do that for each user (`FOR ROLE a`), or is there a blanket way to set that up?

Comment: No, you have to do it for each user that could create objects.